# F1 student in the US: can I visit another University for one term?

Tags: usa, students, student-visa

As an F1 student in the US, can I visit another University in the US for one term to carry out some research project with a professor there?

Comment: Will you continue being enrolled as required in your original school? Does it count as internship or being part of your studies? If I remember correctly, you're a PhD student, so this is probably something your IS office has encountered before - have you asked them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F1 regulations are quite strict and many conditions need to be followed there. So it may not be straightforward. You can always transfer to another university but then only a certain amount of credit may be transferred.

I would look in to the definition of "visit", as long as you are maintaining the required load and following regulations of your current university and department you are fine.